# A poorly approximated crossword

Tags: mathematics, word, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, crosswords

Today's crossword topic is flowers:

[image: Screenshot of the puzzle.]

##### Across

- Daffodils, erica, dogbane, ursi, candytuft and tithonia.
- Daphne, eustoma, dianthus, orchid, ixia and dietes.

##### Down

- Alstroemeria, dianella and day.
- Ursinias and petunia.

##### Hints

> The tags [letters](/questions/tagged/letters) and [acrostic](/questions/tagged/acrostic) don’t truly apply, but they *might* help your thought process.
>  I'm pretty sure that $f = 6$.
>  The values for each box aren't quite letters.

---

<sub>*Today's entry is number .1269994261.*</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Across

> Daffodils, erica, dogbane, ursi, candytuft and tithonia. == DEDUCT
>     Daphne, eustoma, dianthus, orchid, ixia and dietes. == DEDOID (? DIVIDE ?)

Down

> Alstroemeria, dianella and day. == ADD
>     Ursinias and petunia. == UP

> Plugging in the Positions (A==1,B==2,C==3,D==4) of the Starting letters:
>  [image: CROSSWORD]

Still Thinking:

> (1) Hmmm, Image has changed in lengths on the ACROSS
>  (2) A435 is a highway in UK , and also a Device from Samsung ....
>  (3) D2 == 16 == P ?
>  (4) A435E == 14355 ?
>  (5) Clue to convert letters to numbers is : 6 == f

Comment: Getting warm. I'll add a hint to help out. :)

Comment: Also, for your "still thinking" section; 1 was a posting error, 2 is way off target, 3 think square, 4 think concatenation. Also, notice the instructions in your solution.

Comment: @Tacoタコス , Thanks for the new hints; I am stuck making sense of DEDOID & the Black Square ....